# Open current browser hotkey

Tags: windows, macos, shortcut, hotkeys

How to open your current browser session. (not open a new browser)

So that you can switch from editor to browser with one shortcut. (not alt tab)

I know you have " CTRL + ~ " to open en close the terminal. 
I also want that for my browser session.

For Mac and Windows would be usefull.

Comment: You have tagged this both Windows and MacOS. But surely the answer isn't the same. Which is it? Anyhow, is this a computer programming question? [I use Microsoft Windows, and I always have Firefox as the first pinned button on the taskbar. Therefore, I can always press Win+1 to bring my Firefox window to the foreground and give it keyboard focus.]

Comment: Your right, I have both Mac and Windows so i figured it would but usefull to know both.

Comment: Okay so you have to add them to your task bar and then use window + 1 to get the first, second etc..

Comment: Thanks this makes my work flow alot quiker

Comment: Well, Win+1 goes to the first taskbar button, Win+2 to the second, and so on. Of course, if you don't pin your taskbar buttons, the nth button will vary. But on every computer I use, I always pin them in the same order: Firefox, Outlook, Windows Explorer, command prompt, Word, Excel, PowerPoint, etc., so in my muscle memory, I know that Win+1 *always* takes me to my browser session, Win+2 always brings up my Outlook window, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

1. store chrome, firefox or anny application in your taskbar.
2. Windows + 1 to get the first
3. etc..

thanks Andreas Rejbrand